# Find path between source and dest

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for python code help to find the distance between source to destination. The input to the function will be number of Rows, number of columns and area which is number of Rows X number of columns matrix.

- We could traverse one cell at a time up, down, left, or right.
- The accessible areas are represented by 1, inaccessible 0 and destination 9.

Sample input

```
numRows=3
numCols=3
alist=[[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,9,1]]
```

Output: Should be an integer representing total distance to destination or -1 if there is no path

For the sample input, the path traversed will be `(0,0)->(1,0)->(2,0)->(2,1)` and the function should return and output of `3`

Here's the pseudo code I could get to but need help figuring out the complete solution.

```
def findthepath(numRows,numCols,alist):
    visited=[]

    if alist[0,0] == 9:
        return 0

    for i in range(numRows):
        for j in range(numCol):
            if alist[i][j] == 1
                visited.append(alist[i][j])
```

Comment: If what you're looking for is the shortest path on a grid between two points I made a video on that a while back: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KiCBXu4P-2Y

Comment: Your first task should be to think about how you would solve this problem. Once you have an algorithm that you think will work, and is likely to be reasonably performant, then begin to code it. As it stands, your code does nothing particularly useful, presumably because you haven't really thought about how to solve this problem.

Comment: @will.fiset that looks good. I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You want a Shortest Path algorithm.  The most commonly used one is Dijkstra's Algorithm.  Slightly difficult to understand, but fairly easy to implement.  Example:  https://gist.github.com/econchick/4666413

I've done this for C#, but not Python.  It could be done fairly easily as the above link demonstrates, though.